# SessionAuthenticationModule missing in IIS

Tags: .net, authentication, iis-7.5, asp.net-identity, federated-identity

I am running IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 and I have Visual Studio 2012 and .Net Framework 4.5.1 installed. (Identity Foundation is integrated with .Net 4.5, so I think I don't have to install it seperately.) We are developing a web app with Claims based federated authentication where in we are writing session token to a cookie. I don't see any cookie getting added to the browser and I noticed that SessionAuthenticationModule is missing in IIS. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a simple windows feature thing. Check the checkbox for 'Turn Windows features on or off' -> Internet information Services -> Internet information Services Hostable Web Core.

[image]